# VS2008 error expected constant expression on declaring array, but no error for this code in GCC

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, constants

I have following function

```
 void someFun(int* ar, const int size) {
      int newAr[size];
      //do something 
 }
```

And I get for this line three errors:

```
Error   1   error C2057: expected constant expression   
Error   2   error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0    
Error   3   error C2133: 'newAr' : unknown size
```

But var **size** is constant! And using gcc this is compiled without errors. Can you tell me what and why is wrong here for vs2008(or for Visual C++ in general maybe)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To answer your question, it's a compiler extension until C++14 gets standardized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`size` is not a constant expression. The term "constant expression" in the error message refers to the C++ concept of Integral Constant Expression. The whole idea of Integral Constant Expression is that its value should be known at compile time. For example, an integral `const` object declared *with an initializer* can be used as an Integral Constant Expression.

Just because you declared some `int` variable `const` does not turn it into an Integral Constant Expression. Function parameters never form Integral Constant Expressions. This is why you cannot use your `size` to define array size in C++.

GCC compiles your code because it brings over a C-specific feature from C language to C++ as a non-standard extension. Note that in GCC your `size` is not considered constant either. GCC simply does not require array sizes to be constant.

If you switch your GCC compiler into strict and pedantic C++ mode, it will refuse to compile your code just as MSVC++ does.

Answer (score 6):

The size of a static array must be known at compile time (therefore it cannot be a variable, the const keyword means the variable cannot be changed but does not mean the variable is constant throughout the entire length of the program and much less known at compile time). You will have to do something like this:

```
int* newAr = new int[size];
```

or better yet use a vector:

```
std::vector<int>(size);
```

The reason I suggest vector over dynamically allocating an array is that with the array you have to remember to deallocate the memory once you are done with it or else you will leak it. With the vector however, it will manage it's own memory.

You can get additional information on vectors [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). I highly suggest you read up on them they are very useful and are in my case the first container I reach out for most of the time.

P.S: As chris mentioned the reason it worked in gcc is because gcc has had the ability to do this for a while but it is a non-standard extension and therefore not portable. Fortunately, I believe it has been entered into the C++14 standard draft which means soon enough most/all compilers will support it.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `const int size` does not mean that `size` is compile-time constant. It simply means that in `someFun`, you cannot change the value of `size`. However, the value of `size` could be changed between different calls of `someFun`.

Arrays in C/C++ need to have a size that is known at compile-time.